# Error with VSTS and Azure Deploy Continuous Delivery

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to get my successfully building VSTS project (an ASP.NET Core 2.0 / React-Redux basic project as setup by the VS2017 file/new wizard) to deploy to Azure. I've pulled my source from github.

When the app service deploy starts, it runs until an error happens: (see: Error: No package found with specified pattern).

```
Starting: Azure App Service Deploy: svcc-reaxxx
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure App Service Deploy
Description  : Update Azure Web App Services, Web App On Linux , Function Apps, Mobile Apps using Web Deploy / Kudu REST APIs
Version      : 3.3.15
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://aka.ms/azurermwebdeployreadme)
==============================================================================
Got connection details for Azure App Service:'svcc-react2'
Error: No package found with specified pattern
Successfully updated deployment History at https://svcc-reaxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/deployments/715065743
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Azure App Service Deploy: svcc-reaxxx
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Starting: Post Job Cleanup
******************************************************************************
Cleaning any cached credential from repository: pkellner/svcc-reacxx (Git)
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/pkellner/svcc-reaxx.git
git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/pkellner/svcc-reaxx.git
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Post Job Cleanup
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Build
******************************************************************************
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your App Service Deploy step configuration? What is happening is that it can't find the zip file to deploy.

Comment: What's the detail setting of App Service Deploy task? Set system.debug variable to true and queue build, then post the detail log here.

Comment: Here is my config for Azure App Service Depoly https://www.dropbox.com/s/1oqze2zlm0q5nd5/a1.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default core template publishes the files to artifact folder, so you need to specify artifact folder if you don’t change it.

So, using `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip` instead.

The sample tasks:

1. NPM install
2. .NET Core Restore
3. .NET Core Build
4. .NET Core Publish (Arguments: `--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`; Check Zip Published Projects and Publish Web Projects options)
5. Azure App Service Deploy task (Package or folder: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip`)

Comment: Thanks @starain-MSFT  That did work, however the deploy does not seem to be copying assets (directories) I've got in my wwwroot directory. They show going buy in VSTS, but they don't show up on the host and when I console in, I don't see them either.